# Netlify Access-Control-Allow-Origin Policy

Tags: cors, netlify

Have the "No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource" error. I am new to Netlify and coding in general.

I tried to deploy a weather app which, of course, fetches weather data from a free API with HTTP protocol.
I have a netlify.toml file which looks like this:

```
[[headers]]
  for = "/*"
    [headers.values]
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

and a _headers file which looks like this:

```
/*
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Still the error shows:
Access to fetch at ‘https://api.weatherunlocked.com/api/forecast/’ from origin ‘https://kravetskyi-weather-app.netlify.app’ has been blocked by CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request’s mode to ‘no-cors’ to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

At this point I am not sure what to do, tried to deploy on Vercel, added vercel.json file to enable CORS but the error persists

Here is the repo for the app in case it might help:
https://github.com/Kravetskyi/weather-app